# Add data to list when data are mapped

Tags: java, list, spring-batch, mapper

I wonder how to add retrieve data from databases and add into list when using this kind of method.

```
 @Bean
    public ItemReader<A> Reader() {
        JdbcCursorItemReader<A> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<A>();

        try {
            String sql = "SELECT .... ";
            reader.setSql(sql);
            reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
            reader.setRowMapper(new Mapper());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return reader;
    }
```

As you can see, all the data will be map into Mapper, but how can I add data to list ?

Comment: This seems to be a question about spring-batch, but you didn't tag it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code just create a structure that you can use to fetch data from database.
To actually get data you should iterate it with this structure.
For more details take a look at [usage of JdbcCursorItemReader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#JdbcCursorItemReader)

Comment: where can I add data to list ?

Comment: Because you are using `CampaignMapper` that does some mapping between database representation and Java entity you should change your code from usage of `<A>` to your actual Java entity class (maybe `Campaign`) and you need call to `Reader()` and then use the returned reader as

Comment: ```java
ItemReader<Campaign> reader = Reader();  
ExecutionContext executionContext = new ExecutionContext();  
reader.open(executionContext);  
List<Campaign> campaigns = new ArrayList();  
Campaign entity = null;  
do {  
    entity = reader.read();  
    if (entity != null)   
        campaigns.add(entity);  
    else break;  
} while (true);  
itemReader.close(executionContext);  
return campaigns;```

Comment: @JohnJoe have you tried solution suggested by me and applied to your entities?

Comment: I will let you know after I try